# Undefined variable and the compiler optimization

Tags: c, compiler-construction, undefined

I have a question about undefined variable and the demonstrated snipped code in down below:

After `func_1()` --- it will push `A` into the stack and set the value of that memory into 40 and then pop `A` out of the stack.

After `func_2()` --- it will push `A` into the stack again and inherit the value set before and the print out value will be 40.

```
void func_1()
{ int A = 40;}

void func_2()
{ int A; printf("%d/n",A);}

void main (void)
{
  func_1();
  func_2();
}
```

If we change the name `A` in `func_2()` into `B` to test the use of stack, and put extra code in it to test the use of the pool of named variables:

```
int A; printf("%d\n", A);
```

On my computer, it says `B` is 40, `A` is 0.

What I was wondering is, if the compiler has a pool of named variables that it reuses to help it optimize the compiled code(?), then why did I get a 0 on `A`?
When is the compiler use the pool?

My question is based on this slide :
http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c/131-I_am_now_going_to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the variable `A` in the function `func_2();` is allocated in the same stack position that the value `40` was (in the `func_1()`). Since you have not initialized the variable in the `func_2()` it will print the variable with a random value that it is in memory in this case `40` (because it was never overridden). It is similar to the scenario when the users free a pointer and then claim that they are able too see its content afterwards, although they may or may not see that value the behaviour is considered to be **undefined**. Needless to say that you should not rely on such behavior!

I have made a simple test, *to prove* that it has nothing to do with the variables' names:

```
void func_1()
{ 
    int A = 40; 
    int B = 10;
    printf("Memory A = %p Memory B = %p\n",&A, &B);
}

void func_2()
{ int B; printf("B = %d Memory B = %p\n",B, &B);}

void main (void)
{
  func_1();
  
  func_2();
  printf("\n");
}
```

**output**:

```
Memory A = 0x7fff58f86b5c Memory B = 0x7fff58f86b58
B = 40 Memory B = 0x7fff58f86b5c
```

As you can see although `B = 10` in `func_1()` in `func_2()`the print value was `40`. why? if you check the memory address of the variable `A` in `func_1()` is `0x7fff58f86b5c` the same memory address occupied by the variable `B`in `func_2()`.

Answer (score 3):

The character in the slide is playing the role of an idiot inventing an idea that seems to explain behaviour that he doesn't understand. There is no pool of named variables.

The behaviour of this code is undefined and can not be relied upon. If it happens to behave at runtime so as to print the value 40, that is merely an accident of the implementation.